# Laplacian of the cosine of a dot product

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis

I wish to find the laplacian of $\cos(\bf{a}\cdot{r}\bf)$ where $\bf a$ is a constant vector.

So this is $\nabla^2[\cos(\bf a\cdot\bf r)]$. I suspect the right approach is to find the component of some component of the result and use this to generalise but I'm not sure how to do this...

For example, let $\bf r$ $=(r_1,\cdots r_n)$. Taking the dot product with $\bf a$ gives $a_1r_1+\cdots a_nr_n$. As such we want the laplacian of $\cos (a_1r_1+\cdots a_nr_n)$. With respect to the $pth$ component, $\frac{\partial cos(a_p\cdot r_p)}{\partial p}=-\sin(\bf a\cdot r)$$a_p$ so $\nabla [\cos (\bf a\cdot r)]=$$-\sin(\bf a\cdot r)a$ and we can do something similar for the Laplacian. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

In 2D,

$$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\cos(a_xx+a_yy)=-a_x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(a_xx+a_yy)=-a_x^2\cos(a_xx+a_yy).$$

We can immediately deduce

$$\nabla^2\cos(\mathbb a\cdot\mathbb r)=-\mathbb a^2\cos(\mathbb a\cdot\mathbb r).$$